# Python locally installed package, module not defined

Tags: python, package

I have a local package set up like this:

```
D:.
|   .gitignore
|   LICENSE
|   pyproject.toml
|   README.md
|   requirements.txt
+---.venv
|   |   ...            
+---mypackage
|   |   __init__.py
|   +---moduleA
|   |   |   module_a_src.py
|   |   |   module_a_helpers.py          
|   +---tools
|   |       tools.py 
\---tests
```

The `__init__.py` file is empty. The `tools.py` file contains the following:

```
def working(string):
    print(string)

print("here i am")
```

I installed the package in edit mode to my local venv using `pip install -e .`

I don't have/want entry points yet. I can run the following from the shell and it works as expected:

```
$ py -c "from mypackage.tools import tools; tools.working('foo')"
here i am
foo
(.venv)
```

**However, I want to be able to run** `py -c "import mypackage; tools.working('foo')"`. I tried adding the following to the `__init__.py` file:

```
from tools import tools

# other things that didn't work and return the same error:
# from .tools import tools
# import tools.tools
# from . import tools
# from mypackage.tools import tools
```

But I get this:

```
$ py -c "import mypackage; tools.working('foo')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tools' is not defined
here i am
(.venv)
```

I tried adding an empty `__init__.py` to the tools folder, no luck.

The `pyproject.toml` contains this, if that matters:

```
[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = [".", "mypackage"]
```

Comment: The only name `import mypackage` is going to define is `mypackage`. You *can't* inject another name into your global namespace like this. The change to `__init__.py` *would* let you write `import mypackage; my package.tools.working("foo")`, since now `tools` will be an *attribute* of the package.

Comment: @chepner okay, thank you. this might be a different question, but `py -c "from tools import tools; tools.working('foo')"` works with an empty `__init__.py` file in the package directory. (it prints `here i am\nfoo`). Why can I access the `tools` module like this, even though it doesn't show up in `pip list` (only `mypackage`) is there. I think I only want to access the `tools` module via `mypackage.tools` in case I am lazy and have multiple custom packages with their own tools.

Comment: `py -c '...'` adds the current working directory to the front of your search path. Is `mypackage` the current working directory?

Comment: the cwd contains `mypackage` (as well as venv, toml, etc.)